# How to integrate object detection model with coreML and objective-c

Tags: objective-c, coreml, apple-vision

I convert MTCNN caffe model to coreML for object detection. And follow Vision guide in object-c projects as below:

```
MLModel *model = [[[net12 alloc] init] model];
VNCoreMLModel *coreMLModel = [VNCoreMLModel modelForMLModel: model error:nil];
VNCoreMLRequest *coreMLRequest = [[VNCoreMLRequest alloc] initWithModel: coreMLModel completionHandler:
                        (VNRequestCompletionHandler) ^(VNRequest *request, NSError *error){
```

The defined output are two MLMultiArray, one is for the confidence and the other is for boundingBox.

How can i convert the MLMultiArray to get confidence value and boundingBox value?

There are some examples with swift for object detection https://github.com/apple/turicreate/tree/master/userguide/object_detection
 , but i can't find similar examples with objective-c.